# Exchange Rate SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-structures

I need to design in SQL Server a history archive exchange rate. In my program have to be able to access the values ​​of the exchange rate on the day x (x is the parameter).

The solution that I thought of is:

```
CREATE TABLE HISTORY (
Currency int, 
Value double, 
Date datetime)
```

There are, in your opinion, a more effective and more efficient solution?

Comment: I wanted my question to be seen by many users as a SQL issue, unrelated to service management database.

Comment: What about using third party web API services like [openexchangerates.org](https://openexchangerates.org/documentation) in your program rather than maintaining it in your own database?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to my mind is datatypes.

Do not know what mssql version you are using but there are *money* and *smallmoney* data types that represent monetary or currency values and they take 8 or 4 bytes. I don't think exchange rate ever exceeds *smallmoney* range.

Unless you want to store rate changes during the day, there is no need of using *datetime* type. It takes 8 bytes while *date* takes only 3 bytes.